# Regarding the meaning of 'was likely to be' in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> A 
>   spectacular conclusion of one of the popular electric exhibitions of the 
>   time **was likely to be** the electrification of a boy suspended by many 
>   silk threads from the rafters; his hair stood on end and sparks could 
>   be drawn from the tip of his nose.

Does the sentence mean the most spectacular conclusion *was in fact* that of the electrification of the boy, or that the electrification of the boy was among the likeliest conclusions to happen at that time and it could have happened or not ?

Comment: This question ***is likely to be closed*** for lack of evidence of prior research. But it might not be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The writer is saying that the exhibition usually, but not always, concluded by electrifying a boy. Compare "likely" and "certain".